# Grab the content of tcl namespace from one interpreter and pass to another interpreter

Tags: c++, namespaces, tcl, interpreter

I use cpptcl.hpp library to create TCL interpreters and evaluate some the expressions. Now I stuck in one problem: In one interpreter (Tcl::interpreter interp1;) I have a namespace called MyNamespace in one interpreter, where there are some variables and procedures defined, and I want to be able to evaluate some TCL expressions in another interpreter (Tcl::interpreter interp2;) by using the predefined variables and procedures in MyNamespace namespace. How I can do that?

Comment: This sounds a lot like what aolserver does for initializing tcl interpreters.  It's messy, but it works pretty well.

Comment: Do you want to copy the state from interp1 to interp2 and run your commands, or do you want to call the command from interp2 and have it evaluated in interp2? On top of that, are they completely separate interpreters or ones created via [interp create] in tcl? I'm guessing the first, but it's worth asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. At least, not easily.

Of course, if your interp does only contain pure Tcl code, and no packages loaded, you are able, in principle, to serialize everything (to a string) and evaluate it in an another interp; the wiki has examples on this (search for "saving state" etc).

But to me it looks like you're trying to create a "reference" interp and then use it as a kind of template.  If so, I would instead just write a code which sets up an interp and then would call it each time to get an appropriately prepared interp.

Comment: Things like traces or commands that are implemented in C by some extension can be very hard to duplicate. Callbacks attached to timer or channel events are another thing that it's easy to forget. In short, copying the namespace isn't too hard but that doesn't mean it will _work_ in the other interp…